# Add a link to unflag all node

Tags: flags

By default, it just available to [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) or unflag an item, [**reference here**](http://drupal.org/node/305086#flagging). I want to add a link to unflag all flagged node of current user, is there any way to do that?

At this moment, I get the code to clean all flagged node, but I don't know how to make this snippet as a link

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {flag_content} WHERE sid = %d", flag_get_sid());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module that implements [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).  Use that to create a path and a custom callback function that will run your query.  Something like:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['flags/remove/%user'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_remove_flags',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access callback' => 'MYMODULE_check_access',
    'access arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

// Adding custom functions, etc
```

To get started on creating a custom module, the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules)

Answer (score 1):

I used this workaround to implement an "unflag spam" feature. Basically, I created a second (global) flag "no spam" that moderators can use in a few to now show nodes that have been flagged for spam.

Screenshots (right click and open in new window for full size):
[image: view that shows content flagged for spam]

flag_spam counter settings:
[image: spam flag]

flag_nospam setting
[image: flag_nospam setting]

The "flag link" fields will set the "nospam" flag to suppress those nodes from the view. I didn't see a choice for which flag the flag links applies to. I assume you'll have to add the "flag_spam counter" relationship.